# mysql trigger inserts into table B on table A insert, which then has another insert trigger on table B to insert into table C

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have three tables: **A,B,C**
A-B = 1:M relationship
B-C = 1:1 relationship

I created a trigger on table A as such:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_tableA_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Insert multiple records
  -- Insert into table B (id, foo) values (NULL,v)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There is also a trigger on table B after insert as such:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_tableB_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tableB
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- insert into tableC values (NEW.id, NEW.foo)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A single insert on table A would trigger multiple inserts on table B.
A single insert on table B would trigger single insert on table C.

My question I guess is that would it be reasonable to have these "ripple" triggers implemented this way because I understand that values may be inserted into table in bulk, rather than one by one. Single inserts would be make sense however I am not sure whether it is feasible in a larger scale.

Plus, how does the database engine perform these actions if the records are inserted in bulk compared to simply inserting one record? is there a difference?

Comment: Given your design multiple inserts to b in after_tableA_insert would result in multiple inserts to c (that;s what for each row does).And I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve - you haven't said.

Comment: yes that is what's desired. For each new record in B, there will be a record in C. But for one new record in A, there will be multiple records in B. It's not exactly a debugging problem, more about best practice and a better understanding

Comment: Best practice is a matter of opinion and only you can say for your environment. I will say that given the code published it would appear to be possible to insert to table b without going through the process which involves your first trigger - that may or may not be desirable.